# Bin Packing: Set amount on bins, want to minimize the max bin weight

Tags: optimization, complexity-theory, combinations, bin-packing

Given *n* bins of infinite capacity, I want to pack *m* items into them (each with a specific weight), whilst minimizing the weight of the heaviest bin.

This isn't a traditional bin packing / knapsack problem where a bin has a finite capacity and you attempt to minimize the amount of bins used; I have a set amount of bins and want to use them all in order to make the heaviest bin's weight as low as possible.

Is there a name for this problem? I have looked through a number of papers with key words, but I have found nothing similar.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If the amount of bins is the constraint, instead of the capacity of bins, then it's not a bin packing, it's a [multiprocessor scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling) problem.

Usually, you can approach this by a LPT algorithm with pretty good results. Optimizations will be needed though and that's where the fun lies.

Comment: Thank you for recognising the name of the problem! I am writing my PhD thesis and my memories of these algorithms are not very fresh! And thanks to you I can now justify my LPT strategy with the proper citations!

Answer (score 0):

It's a form of a **2D** bin packing problem. The first dimension is a limit on *capacity per bin* (= **hard constraint**), the second dimension is to minimize *the weight of the heaviest bin* (= **soft constraint**).

With [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner), I 'd start from [the cloud balance example](http://blog.athico.com/2010/10/planning-processing-in-cloud.html) and implement it like this:

```
rule "maxCapacity"
  when
    // When there is a bin ...
    $bin : Bin($binCapacity : binCapacity)
    // ... where the total of the item capacity is bigger than the bin capacity ...
    $itemCapacityTotal : Number(intValue > $binCapacity) from accumulate(
        ItemAssignment(
            bin == $bin,
            $itemCapacity : itemCapacity),
        sum($itemCapacity)
    )
  then
    // ... then lower the hard score with the insufficient capacity
    insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("maxCapacity",
            ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_HARD,
            $itemCapacityTotal.intValue() - $binCapacity,
            $bin));
end


rule "calculateWeight"
  when
    $bin : Bin()
    $itemWeightTotal : Number() from accumulate(
        ItemAssignment(
            bin == $bin,
            $itemWeight : itemWeight),
        sum($itemWeight)
    )
  then
    insertLogical(new BinToWeight($bin, $itemWeightTotal);
end
rule "minimizeWeight"
  when
    BinToWeight($bin : bin, $itemWeightTotal : itemWeightTotal)
    not BinToWeight (itemWeightTotal > $itemWeightTotal,  bin != $bin)
  then
    insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("minimizeWeight",
            ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_SOFT,
            $itemWeightTotal,
            $bin));
end
```

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, but I have no idea how to implement this :(